# maximize $\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$ if $a+c+x+y=1$, $(a+c)^2+(x+y)^2+2xc\leq 1-2\gamma$, $0\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, perturbation-theory

Edit: I am using the natural logarithm in what follows.

I want to figure out how to show by hand that the maximum of 
$$\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$$
when
$$a\geq 0, c\geq 0, x \geq 0, y \geq 0,$$
$$a+c+x+y=1,$$
$$(a+c)^2+(x+y)^2+2xc\leq 1-2\gamma,$$
where $\gamma$ is a fixed constant such that $4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$,
is $\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)$, which is given by $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$, $x=1-a=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$, $c=y=0$.

I have tried using Lagrange multipliers by changing the last constraint to an equality, but it becomes very messy and I get stuck.

I would also be happy if I could simply show that $\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x \leq \frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)$ for all such $a,c,x,y$. A method I have attempted is to use the concavity of $\log(x)$. The equation of the line that passes through $(2, \log(2))$ and $(3, \log(3))$ is $L(x)=\log(3/2)x-\log(9/8)$. Then by concavity of $\log(x)$ we have $\log(x)\leq L(x)$ for all integers $x$. Then

\begin{align*}&\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x\\
             &\leq L(4)c+L(3)a+L(2)x\\
             &=\log(3/2) (4c+3a+2x+y)-\log(9/8)\\
             &=\log(3/2)\left(\frac{5+3}{2}c+\frac{5+1}{2}a+\frac{5-1}{2}x+\frac{5-3}{2}y\right)-\log(9/8)\\
             &=\log(3/2)\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\right)-\log(9/8)+\log(3/2)\left(\frac{a-x+3(c-y)-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\right)\\
             &=\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)+\log(3/2)\left(\frac{a-x+3(c-y)-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\right).\\
\end{align*}
That means that to obtain the inequality I want, it would suffice to show that $a-x\leq 3(y-c)+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}$. However, I have not had success in proving this inequality. Any suggestions or help is immensely appreciated.

Another option would be to use perturbation techniques, but I do not have experience in this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a $b$ in the middle of your question, but nowhere else. Is that supposed to be $x = 1-a$?

Comment: @VVejalla Yes, it was supposed to be an $x$. I fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)$ is not the maximum of $$f(c,a,x):=\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$$

For example, for $\gamma=4/25$, we have
$$f(4/5,0,0)=\frac{\log(256)}{5}\color{red}{\gt}\frac{\log(162)}{5}=\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4(4/25)}}{2}\log(3/2)$$

---

In the following, let us prove that the maximum of $\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$ is
$$\begin{cases}\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})&\text{if $\ 4/25\le \gamma\lt\frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}$}
\\\\\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)&\text{if $\ \frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}\le\gamma\le 1/4$}\end{cases}$$

We want to find the maximum of $f(c,a,x)$ under the condition that
$$a\geq 0, c\geq 0, x \geq 0, 1-a-c-x \geq 0,$$
$$(a+c)^2+(1-a-c)^2+2xc\leq 1-2\gamma,4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

**Case 1** : $c=0$

We want to find the maximum of $f(0,a,x)$ under the condition that
$$0\le x\le 1-a,\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le a\le\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

Therefore, we get
$$\begin{align}f(0,a,x)&\le f(0,a,1-a)
\\\\&=\log(3/2)a+\log(2)
\\\\&\le\log(3/2)\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}+\log(2)
\\\\&=\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)\end{align}$$

**Case 2** : $c\gt 0$

We want to find the maximum of $f(c,a,x)$ under the condition that
$$a\ge 0, c\gt 0, 0\le 1-a-c,$$
$$0\le x\leq \min\bigg(1-a-c,\frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}\bigg),$$
$$0\le \frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$
Note here that
$$\min\bigg(1-a-c,\frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}\bigg)=\begin{cases}1-a-c&\text{if $\ a(1-a-c)\ge \gamma$}
\\\\\frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}&\text{if $\ a(1-a-c)\lt \gamma$}\end{cases}$$

**Case 2-1** : $a(1-a-c)\ge \gamma$

We have $0\le x\leq 1-a-c$ from which we obtain
$$f(c,a,x)\le f(c,a,1-a-c)=\log(2)c+\log(3/2)a+\log(2):=g(c,a)$$

Suppose that $a=0$. Then, there is no $\gamma$ such that $0\ge\gamma$ and $4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$. So, $a\gt 0$.

So, we want to find the maximum of $g(c,a)$ under the condition that
$$0\lt c\le 1-a-\frac{\gamma}{a},\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$
so
$$g(c,a)\le g\bigg(1-a-\frac{\gamma}{a},a\bigg)=-\log(2)\frac{\gamma}{a}-\log(4/3)a+\log(4):=h(a)$$
We want to find the maximum of $h(a)$ under the condition that
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

We see that $h'(a)$ is decreasing with
$$h'(a)=0\iff a=\sqrt{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(4/3)}\gamma}$$

If $4/25\le \gamma\lt \frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}$, then 
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt \sqrt{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(4/3)}\gamma}\lt \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$$
from which we have
$$h(a)\le h\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(4/3)}\gamma}\bigg)=\log(4)-2\sqrt{\log(2)\log(4/3)\gamma}$$

If $\frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}\le\gamma\le\frac 14$, then
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le \sqrt{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(4/3)}\gamma}$$
So, $h'(a)$ is positive in $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$, so $h(a)$ is increasing from which we have
$$h(a)\lt h\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\bigg)=\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)$$

**Case 2-2** : $a(1-a-c)\lt \gamma$

We have
$$0\le x\leq \frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}$$
from which we obtain 
$$\begin{align}f(c,a,x)&\le f\bigg(c,a,\frac{1-2\gamma-(a+c)^2-(1-a-c)^2}{2c}\bigg)
\\\\&=\log(2)c+\log(3/4)a+\log(2)\frac{-\gamma-a^2+a+c}{c}:=j(c,a)\end{align}$$
where
$$\frac{\partial j}{\partial c}=\log(2)\frac{c^2+\gamma+a^2-a}{c^2}$$

We want to maximize $j(c,a)$ under the condition that
$$0\le a\lt \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 0\lt c\le 1-a,\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a}\lt c$$
$$\frac{1-2a-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le c\le \frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

**Case 2-2-1** : $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$

Then, we have

$$\sqrt{a-a^2-\gamma}\ge\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a}$$

$$\small\frac{1-2a-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le 0\le \frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a}\lt \frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt 1-a$$

So, we want to maximize $j(c,a)$ under the condition that
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\le\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a}\lt c\le \frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

Using that
$$\frac{\partial j}{\partial c}=\log(2)\frac{c^2+\gamma+a^2-a}{c^2}\ge 0\iff c\ge \sqrt{a-a^2-\gamma}$$
 we have
$$\begin{align}j(c,a)&\le\max\bigg(j\bigg(\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a},a\bigg),j\bigg(\frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},a\bigg)\bigg)
\\\\&=\begin{cases}j\bigg(\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a},a\bigg)&\text{if $\ a\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}$}
\\\\j\bigg(\frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},a\bigg)&\text{if $\ a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}$}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

**Case 2-2-1-1** : $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}\le\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\ (\le a)$ which holds only when $2/9\le\gamma\le 1/4$

$$\begin{align}j(c,a)&\le j\bigg(\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a},a\bigg)
\\\\&=h(a)
\\\\&\lt h\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)\end{align}$$

**Case 2-2-1-2** : $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$ which holds only when $4/25\le\gamma\lt 2/9$

**Case 2-2-1-2-1** : $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\le\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}$

$$\begin{align}j(c,a)&\le j\bigg(\frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},a\bigg)
\\\\&=\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})-\log(4/3)a
\\\\&\lt \log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})-\log(4/3)\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}
\\\\&=\frac{\log(3)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(16/3)\end{align}$$

**Case 2-2-1-2-2** : $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$

$$\begin{align}j(c,a)&\le j\bigg(\frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},a\bigg)
\\\\&=\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})-\log(4/3)a
\\\\&\lt\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})-\log(4/3)\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}
\\\\&=\frac{\log(12)}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4}\log(12)\end{align}$$

**Case 2-2-2** : $0\le a\le \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$

Since $\frac{\partial j}{\partial c}=\log(2)\frac{c^2+\gamma+a^2-a}{c^2}\gt 0$, we see that $j(c,a)$ is increasing on $c$. We have

$$\small\frac{a-a^2-\gamma}{a}\le 0\le \frac{1-2a-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le \frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le 1-a$$

So, we want to maximize $j(c,a)$ under the condition that
$$0\le a\le \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, \frac{1-2a-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le c\le \frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}, 4/25\leq \gamma \leq 1/4$$

Hence, we get
$$\begin{align}j(c,a)&\le j\bigg(\frac{1-2a+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2},a\bigg)
\\\\&=\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})-\log(4/3)a
\\\\&\le\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})\end{align}$$

---

**Conclusion** : The maximum of $\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$ is
$$\begin{cases}\log(2)(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma})&\text{if $\ 4/25\le \gamma\lt\frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}$}
\\\\\frac{\log(6)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\log(3/2)&\text{if $\ \frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}\le\gamma\le 1/4$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to think about this problem and write down your answer. I went through your entire solution. A couple of things: (1) You were right about the maximum at $\gamma=4/25$ not being what I said it was. However, I checked on Maple and got a different answer than you. The maximum I got of $\log(4)c+\log(3)a+\log(2)x$ is at $c=4/5$, $a=0$, $x=0$, and $y=1/5$ and I obtained $\approx 1.109$.

Comment: (2) In Case 2-2-1-1 you said that $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{4} \leq \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$ holds for $4/25 \leq \gamma \leq 2/9$, but I found that it actually holds for $2/9 \leq \gamma \leq 1/4$. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Steve : (1) I will check the part. (2) You are right. I've just corrected the inequality. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve : (1) You are right. I've corrected some errors, and I got the value you wrote.

Comment: No problem, thank you. I have a question about Case 2-1, which is when $a(1-a-c)\geq \gamma$. You want to maximize $g(c,a):=\log(2)c+\log(3/2)a+\log(2)$ under the conditions $0<c\leq 1-a-\gamma/2$, $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2} < a < \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$, $4/25 \leq \gamma \leq 1/4$. I understand why $a$ has to be in this range, but what I am confused about is why you consider when $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\leq \sqrt{\frac{\log(2)\gamma}{\log(4/3)}}=a$ since $a$ cannot be in this range.

Comment: @Steve: I should have explained the part more explicitly. I’ve just added some explanations in my answer. What I meant is as follows : When $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le \sqrt{\frac{\log(2)\gamma}{\log(4/3)}}$, we get $h'(a)\gt 0$ in $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}$. From this, we see that $h(a)$ is increasing. So, we get $h(a)\lt h(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2})$.

Comment: @Steve: Ah, your question is about "why I consider it", because I separated Case 2-1 into two cases: $4/25\le \gamma\lt \frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}$ or $\frac{\log(2)\log(4/3)}{(\log(8/3))^2}\le \gamma\le\frac 14$. In the latter case, we get $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2}\le\sqrt{\frac{\log(2)\gamma}{\log(4/3)}}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary transformations.}}$

The task is to maximize the function
$$f(x,a,c) = (x+2c)\log 2 + a\log 3\tag1$$
over non-negative $a,c,x,y,$ under the conditions
$$x+y+a+c = 1,\quad (x+y)^2+(c+a)^2+2cx\le 1-2\gamma,\tag2$$
or
\begin{cases}
x+y+a+c = 1\\
(c+a)(x+y) - cx\ge\gamma\\
x\ge0,\quad y\ge0,\quad a\ge0,\quad c\ge0,\tag3
\end{cases}
where
$$\gamma\in\left[0,\dfrac14\right].\tag4$$

Denote 
$$b= a+c,\quad z = 1-y,\quad g(z,b,c) = f(z-b,b-c,c),$$
then
$$g(z,b,c) = (z-b+2c)\log2+(b-c)\log3\tag5,$$

\begin{cases}
b(1-b) - c(z-b)\ge\gamma\\
0\le c\le b\le z\le1.\tag6
\end{cases}

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Searching of the global maximum.}}$

Maximum of the linear function $g(z,b,c)$ corresponds to the edges of area, wherein maximum of the linear function with the linear constraints - to the vertices.

Since from $(5)$
$$g(z,b,c) = z\log2+b\log\dfrac32+c\log\dfrac43,$$
then the global maximum corresponds to the point with the maximal distance from the start of the coordinates at the certain direction.

**Vertices.**

If **c=0** then

$$b^2-b + \gamma = 0,$$
$$\max g_v(z,b,0) = g\left(1,\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2,0\right),$$
$$\max g_v(z,b,0) = \left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log2
+\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log3.$$

If **b=c** then 
\begin{cases}
b(1-z)=\gamma\\
z = b,
\end{cases}
$$\max g_v(z,b,b) = g\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2,
\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2,\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right),$$
$$\max g_v(z,b,b) = \left(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}\right)\log2.$$

If **z=b** then 
\begin{cases}
b(1-b)=\gamma\\
c=b,
\end{cases}
$$\max g_v(b,b,c) = \left(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}\right)\log2.$$

If **z=1** then 
\begin{cases}
(b-c)(1-b)=\gamma\\
c = 0
\end{cases}
$$\max g_v(1,b,c) = g\left(1,\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2,0\right),$$
$$\max g_v(1,b,c) = \left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log2
+\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log3.$$

The greatest value over vertices is
$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{g_v(z,b,c) = 
\begin{cases}
\left(1+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}\right)\log2,\quad\text{if}\quad \gamma\in[0,\gamma_v)\\[4pt]
\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log2
+\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}2\right)\log3,
\quad\text{if}\quad \gamma\in[\gamma_v,0.25],
\end{cases}}}\tag7$$
where 
$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\gamma_v= \dfrac14 - \dfrac14\left(\dfrac{\log\,^3/_2}{\log\,^8/_3}\right)^2\approx0.20728.}}\tag8$$

**Optimization task.**

Optimization task for non-linear constraint $(6.1)$ can be solved by Lagrange multipliers method, applied to the function
$$G(z,b,c,\lambda) = (z-b+2c)\log2+(b-c)\log3+\lambda(b-b^2+bc-cz - \gamma).$$
The stationary points of $G$ can be defined from the system $G'_z = G'_b = G'_c = G'_\lambda = 0,$ or
\begin{cases}
\log2-\lambda c = 0\\
-\log2+\log3+\lambda(1-2b+c) = 0\\
2\log2-\log3+\lambda(b-z) = 0\\
b(1-b+c)-cz - \gamma = 0.
\end{cases}

Then, taking in account $(6.1),$
$$
\begin{cases}
\log2-\lambda c = 0\\
\log3+\lambda(1-2b) = 0\\
\log2 + \lambda(1-b+c-z) = 0\\
b(1-b+c)-cz - \gamma = 0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(2b-1)\log2= c\log3\\
z=1-b+2c\\
b(1-b+c) - c(1-b+2c) = \gamma,
\end{cases}$$
\begin{cases}
c=r(2b-1)\\
z=(4r-1)b-(2r-1)\\
b(1-b)+c(2b-1-2c) = \gamma\\
0\le c\le b \le z \le1\\
r=\dfrac{\log2}{\log3} = \log_23\approx0.63093,\tag9
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
c=r(2b-1)\\
z=1-b+2c\\
b(1-b)+(1-2r)(2b-1)^2=\gamma\\
b\in\left[\dfrac12,\dfrac{2r}{4r-1}\right]\approx[0.5,0.82814]\\
\gamma\in\left[0,\dfrac{(2r-1)^2}{(4r-1)^2}\right]\approx[0,0.02953],\tag{10}
\end{cases}

$$b(1-b)+r(1-2r)(4b^2-4b+1) = \gamma,$$
$$s(b^2-b) + 2r^2-r+\gamma = 0,\quad\text{where}\quad s=8r^2-4r+1\approx1.66086,\tag{11}$$
$$b= \dfrac12 +\dfrac12\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s},\quad c=r\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s},\quad
z= \dfrac12 +\dfrac{4r-1}2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s},$$
$$g_m(z,b,c) = (4r-1)\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s}\log2+\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{1-2r}2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s}\right)\log3\\
 = \left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{8r^2-4r+1}2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s}\right)\log3
 = \left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{s}2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-4\gamma}s}\right)\log3,$$
$$g_m(z,b,c) \le \dfrac{1+\sqrt s}2 \log3 < {1+1.3}2 = 1.15\log3,$$
$$g_v(z,b,c) > r\left(1+\sqrt{1-4\cdot0.3}\right)\log3 > 0.63(1+0.9)\log3 > g_m(z,b,c),$$

$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\max g(z,b,c)=g_v(z,b,c).}}\tag{12}$$

Thus, the global maximum of $f(x,a,c)$ under the given conditions 
**is defined by the formulas** $\color{brown}{\mathbf{(7)-(8)}}\ $ (see also Wolfram Alpha plot).

[image: The global maximum]

Comment: That's nice, but the question is about the maximum.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you, fixed.